# BLE device sends keystrokes to PC and PC write to cusom characteristics simultaneously, possible?

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, hid

Hello I got BLE HID ( keyboard ) with added custom characteristics to it. I want it to send keystrokes and simultaneously got option to write to its characteristics.

If I conect that device from windows ( from bluetooth tab ), PC recives keystrokes.
But if I connect by bleak from python to write characteristics, PC doesnt recives keystrokes.
Is there any option to write to chracteristics of already connected BLE HID device?

Update 1:
As "device" i mean esp32 using modified adafruit BleKeyboard library

Modified part:

```cpp
  BLEService *pService2;
  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic;

  pService2 = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
  pCharacteristic = pService2->createCharacteristic(
  CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                         
    BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                                         
    BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                                       );
  pCharacteristic->setValue("Hello, World!");
  pService2->start();
```

Comment: It depends on your device. It looks like your keyboard can work with only one connection. So when you connects to it to write characteristic it stops working as HID (discopnnects or simple puts it on pause). You should have only single connection to be able to do what you need. Unfortunately there is no simple/easy solution for that.